# TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS] with path that contain Japanese

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the post method in Nodejs with the path containing Japanese. But I got the error:

TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters

The path looks like:
D:\SourceCode\Backend\controllers\PPTXサンプル.pptx

I tried using **encodeURIComponent()** but it didn't solve the problem.

```
const file= [
        {
            url:"D:\\SourceCode\\Backend\\controllers\\PPTXサンプル.pptx",
            name: "PPTXサンプル.pptx",
        },

    Promise.resolve()
                    .then(() => {
                        return sprLib.renewSecurityToken();
                    })
                    .then((strDigest) => {
                        return sprLib.folder(req.body.serverRelativeUrl).upload({
                            name: file.name,
                            data: fs.readFileSync(file.url),
                            requestDigest: strDigest,
                            overwrite: true,
                        });
                    })
                    .then((objFile) => {
                        console.log(
                            "SUCCESS: `" +
                            objFile.Name +
                            "` uploaded to: `" +
                            objFile.ServerRelativeUrl +
                            "`"
                        );
                    })
                    .catch((strErr) => {
                        console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++");
                        console.error(strErr);
                    })
```

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: @eol  yes , i posted my code

Comment: Please delete duplicating back slashes D:\\SourceCode\\Backend\\controllers\\PPTXサンプル.pptx"

Comment: @pavlo I changed to   "D:/Backend/controllers/PPTXサンプル.pptx"   or   "D:\Backend\controllers\PPTXサンプル.pptx"     but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @pavlo Why? This is correct. `\ ` is the escape character in JS strings (for example `\n` gives a newline), so literal use of `\ ` must be escaped by another `\ `. The string literal `"Hello\\World"` has the value of `Hello\World`. (Unless you are using `String.raw` but that's a different story.)

Answer (score 1):

I used **encodeURI()** to encode the name **"PPTXサンプル.pptx"** in this Japanese. 
And API automatically deencode Japanese after uploading the file